# HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/xxxx?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus-signin

I am trying to get the G+ profile of the logged in user. Here is my code.

```
@app.route('/Home')
def home():
    """Home Route"""
    session['state'] = state
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    else:
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        plus_service = discovery.build('plus', 'v1', http_auth)
        people_document = plus_service.people().get(userId=users.get_current_user().user_id()).execute()
        #files = drive_service.files().list().execute()
        return json.dumps(people_document)

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        'client_secrets.json',
         scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
         redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True),)
    if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))
```

When I hit the URL /Home, I get the following error.

```
WARNING  2016-04-20 09:50:01,331 util.py:134] build() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
INFO     2016-04-20 09:50:01,392 discovery.py:817] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/xxxxx?alt=json
WARNING  2016-04-20 09:50:01,395 urlfetch_stub.py:540] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']
ERROR    2016-04-20 09:50:04,242 wsgi.py:279] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/mainsite/__init__.py", line 61, in home
    people_document = plus_service.people().get(userId=users.get_current_user().user_id()).execute()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/Rainbow/gaenv/googleapiclient/http.py", line 760, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/xxxx?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
INFO     2016-04-20 09:50:04,386 module.py:787] default: "GET /Home HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: IAP Google's Identify Aware Proxy